# Send a notification when a record changed in database pivot table laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I want to send a message to my header (which I think means all views) notification part when a record changes in my pivot table so here is my code

This is client model

```
public function sellmanlist() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\User' , 'client_user','client_id');
}
```

This is client controller to save sellman list

```
public function assignsellman(Client $client) {
  $user = User::all();
  $client_list = Client::all();
  return view('admin.client.assign',compact('client_list','user'));
}

public function assignsellmanSave(Request $request) {
  $user = User::all();
  $client_list = Client::all();
  $client = Client::with('sellmanlist')->firstOrFail();
  $sellman = $request->input('sellman');
  $client_name = $request->input('client');
  $client->sellmanlist()->attach($sellman,['client_id' =>$client_name]);
  return view('admin.client.assign',compact('client_list','user'));
}
```

now here I want to send a notification to the user that a client is assigned to you in his profile any clue how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create notification class for notifying user about client added

```
php artisan make:notification ClientAdded
```

after that edit this file which you find in a new folder `App\Notifications`

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class ClientAdded extends Notification
{

    protected $client;

    public function __construct($client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database']; //need to create notifications table check the below link
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
       return [
              'client_id' => $this->client->id,
              'client_name' => $this->client->name,
          ];
    }

}
```

Add below code in your `User` model and be sure your `User` model should have used `Notifiable` trait

```
public function sendClientAddedNotification($client)
{
    $this->notify(new ClientAdded($client));
}
```

Import these class to `User` model

```
use App\Notifications\ClientAdded;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
```

Now in controller after client saved

```
$user->sendClientAddedNotification($client);
```

Here the **$user** should be the user whom you want to notify

Check this for **Database notification** https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications#database-notifications

Comment: thanks man you are my savior today :) that is complete i will try it and let you know the result thanks again

Comment: just 1 thing can i not use email ?? like i want to send notification in a notification panel like facebook for them ?? i mean can i compact it to a view ?

Comment: be sure `$user` instance should be the user whom you want to send notification

Comment: sure, let me change the code, we just need to change the `via` in notification

Comment: @Farshad i have updated answer for database notification but then you have to create a `notifications` table and a Model for it to access. I have added a link at bottom check that link it has details for creating notifications table. let me know if you have any problem

Comment: Thats working like magic :) cant believe it . i just dont understand 1 part if u can explain or show it to me . where exactly did you tell laravel to send notification if a record just changed in pivot table ? :D

Comment: this is the code `$user->sendClientAddedNotification($client);`

Comment: i noticed some thing strange client_id is always store in table 2 no matter what changes in tables :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176253/discussion-between-rkj-and-farshad).